# EntityFramework EntityCollection Observing CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inotifycollectionchanged, entitycollection

I'm using EntityFramework database first in an application. I would like somehow to be notified of changes to an `EntityCollection` in my ViewModel. It doesn't directly support `INotifyCollectionChanged` (why?) and I haven't been successful in finding another solution.

Here's my latest attempt, which doesn't work because the `ListChanged` event doesn't appear to get raised:

```
public class EntityCollectionObserver<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged where T : class
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public EntityCollectionObserver(EntityCollection<T> entityCollection)
        : base(entityCollection)
    {
        IBindingList l = ((IBindingList)((IListSource)entityCollection).GetList());
        l.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(OnInnerListChanged);
    }

    private void OnInnerListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null) 
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I might observe changes to an `EntityCollection`?

Dan

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264979/changing-association-property-entitycollection-dont-rise-propertychanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it worked in the simple use case noted by @Aron, I couldn't get it to work properly in my actual application.

As it turns out, and for reasons I'm not sure - the inner `IBindingList` of an `EntityCollection` somehow, somewhere, can get changed. The reason my observers weren't being called is because they were looking for changes on an old `IBindingList` that wasn't even being used by the `EntityCollection` any more.

Here is the hack that got it working for me:

```
public class EntityCollectionObserver<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : class
{
    private static List<Tuple<IBindingList, EntityCollection<T>, EntityCollectionObserver<T>>> InnerLists 
        = new List<Tuple<IBindingList, EntityCollection<T>, EntityCollectionObserver<T>>>();

    public EntityCollectionObserver(EntityCollection<T> entityCollection)
        : base(entityCollection)
    {
        IBindingList l = ((IBindingList)((IListSource)entityCollection).GetList());
        l.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(OnInnerListChanged);


        foreach (var x in InnerLists.Where(x => x.Item2 == entityCollection && x.Item1 != l))
        {
            x.Item3.ObserveThisListAswell(x.Item1);
        }
        InnerLists.Add(new Tuple<IBindingList, EntityCollection<T>, EntityCollectionObserver<T>>(l, entityCollection, this));
    }

    private void ObserveThisListAswell(IBindingList l)
    {
        l.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(OnInnerListChanged);
    }

    private void OnInnerListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, that seems like a lot of work... I wonder how that internal list is getting changed.  You were not changing it externally somewhere?  So weird.

Comment: I never worked out when or why it was being changed. Since there is no was to monitor when the inner list is changed even the above solution is unreliable.

I've migrated to STE's for now and am happily making use of TrackableCollection.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried handling
AssociationChanged  Occurs when a change is made to a related end. (Inherited from RelatedEnd.)

It gives arguments showing whether an element was added or deleted and also exposes the element.

Answer (score 1):

How are you mapping the event?  Pasting your code and mapping the event like follows works for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EntityCollection<string> col = new EntityCollection<string>();
        EntityCollectionObserver<string> colObserver = new EntityCollectionObserver<string>(col);

        colObserver.CollectionChanged += colObserver_CollectionChanged;

        col.Add("foo");
    }

    static void colObserver_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entity Collection Changed");
    }
```

Comment: As it turns out, it doesn't work in all cases. See my answer below for a solution that worked for me.