# Changing association property (EntityCollection) don't rise PropertyChanged

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I want to bind some column data of readonly DataGrid to Association property of Entity through Converter (convert collection from this association property to string). When I try to add/remove elements from collection, binding don't fire. PropertyChanged also, don't rising.

```
contractPosition.PropertyChanged += (s, e2) =>
    {
           a = 0;//don't fire
    };

contractPosition.ContractToOrderLinks.Remove(link);
```

Here is the fragment of  contractPosition Entity (generated by EF4):

```
[Association("ContractPosition_ContractToOrderLink", "PositionId", "ContractPositionId")]
        [XmlIgnore()]
        public EntityCollection<ContractToOrderLink> ContractToOrderLinks
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this._contractToOrderLinks == null))
                {
                    this._contractToOrderLinks = new EntityCollection<ContractToOrderLink>(this, "ContractToOrderLinks", this.FilterContractToOrderLinks, this.AttachContractToOrderLinks, this.DetachContractToOrderLinks);
                }
                return this._contractToOrderLinks;
            }
        }
```

Why PropertyChanged  don't rise? How can I implement binding refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different events to listen to:

1. `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`

   Fires when the value of `_contractToOrderLinks` changes. In your sample code, the value **never** changes, the event is **never** called, and the event **never** fires.
2. `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged`

   Fires when an object is added, an object is removed and, when the collection is cleared.
3. `EntityCollection<>.EntityAdded`

   Fires when an object is added.
4. `EntityCollection<>.EntityRemoved`

   Fires when an object is removed. *I am not sure if this fires for each entity when the collection is cleared.*

I prefer to use the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event. However, `EntityCollection<>` explicitly implements the interface so you must cast it first. Try this:

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged)contractPosition.ContractToOrderLinks).CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
           a = 0; //does fire
    };

contractPosition.ContractToOrderLinks.Remove(link);
```

Comment: May be you want to say this: contractPosition.ContractToOrderLinks.EntityRemoved += (s, e2) =>
                        {
                            int a = 0;//does not fire
                        };
                        contractPosition.ContractToOrderLinks.Remove(link);                                 But this also don't work. I don't understand. Why?

Comment: I updated the answer to cast the `ContractToOrderLinks` as an INCC. Your code *should* work. Not clear why it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, its should work. But doesn't! https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B7H2m78QpIkFMzY0NGEwNTUtN2Q5ZS00NjVkLThiOWUtMDI1Y2QxOTM4NTNm&hl=en_US

Comment: _Cannont convert type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<BusinessObjects.ServiceEvent>' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged'_ I only can use your first given option.